TLC experiment interprentation
I am having difficulty interpreting the results of an identification test involving six different standards (dyes) in an unknown mixture of dyes, using silica gel TLC plates and acetone as the mobile phase.
The figure below shows that Erythrosine has been separated from the mixture. However, there is also a blue spot that has remained at the baseline and could potentially be identified as either Janus Green or Toluidine Blue.

I have examined the structure of all the standards provided and listed the (polar) functional groups present in the molecules (figure below).

The problem I have with this experiment is that  I do not understand  why the more polar compound (Erythrosine) travelled far from the baseline, while less polar compound (either Janus Green or Toluidine Blue) did not move at all.

What this TLC shows is that acetone is not a good choice. Dyes either travelled with the mobile phase or stayed on the original spot forever. Do you know (from teacher?) that the dye mixture is supposed to contain only these six components?

Both the Janus Green and Toluidine Blue as basic dyes are probably present as their hydrochlorides, therefore very polar and would need more polar (and/or basic) mobile phase components.

@AChem yes, the dye mixture contains only these 6 components.

@Poutnik, I see what you mean. Thank you!
